# WPF rotating button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-controls

Help me plz. I need to animate rotation of the button on z-axis without using external libraries, only with C# and xaml code.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [Viewport2DVisual3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d.aspx)

The example in the link does exactly that.

**Edit:** Here is the example from the link with an added animation of the Z axis

*Looks like this*
[image]

```
<Viewport3D>
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D x:Name="v2dv3d">
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
            <RotateTransform3D>
                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
            </RotateTransform3D>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                    TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
        <Button Content="Hello, 3D">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <Rotation3DAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="v2dv3d"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform).(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:2"
                                                    BeginTime="0:0:0">
                                <Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                                </Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                                <Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                                </Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                            </Rotation3DAnimation>
                            <Rotation3DAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="v2dv3d"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform).(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:2"
                                                    BeginTime="0:0:2">
                                <Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="-90" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                                </Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                                <Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                                </Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                            </Rotation3DAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not precise. I need to animate this process.

Comment: @Eugene: Updated my answer with a z axis animation. Paste it and try it :)

Comment: @Meleak This is a Y-axis rotation.  If you change the axis to Z, you can also simplify the storyboard, because the button will never turn away from the camera.

Comment: @Kimberly: True, this isn't Z-axis (mixed up 3d with Z-axis) but I have a feeling this effect was what the OP wanted. Like a rotating logotype in 3D (I could be wrong of course)

Comment: @Meleak pls, see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499764/rotate-a-panel-90?noredirect=1#comment21947277_15499764 I need rotate my panel when user click on the button...

Answer (score 1):

Transformations may help you in this case. Look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx) if that helps.

> The RotateTransform class is used to rotate a WPF object in an X-Y
>   plane. It can be applied via XAML or directly via imperative code.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to rotate your button about the Z axis, then you won't need any 3D graphics.  All UIElements (such as Buttons) have the property [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx), which enables basic transformation of their default appearance.  By means of [Storyboards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx), WPF allows you to [animate almost any dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx#applyanimationstoproperty).  You can use a storyboard, triggered on load, to animate the Angle property of a RotateTransform applied to the button:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" Content="Wheeee!">
  <Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRotation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle">
          <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Button.Triggers>
  <Button.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform x:Name="ButtonRotation" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" Angle="45"/>
  </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

The Viewport2DVisual3D, as recommended by @Meleak, also supports animation, and is fun to play with if you have time.  To animate the MSDN example, you need to add a name to the AxisAngleRotation3D element and switch it to target the Z axis:

```
<AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="RotateAboutZ" Angle="40" Axis="0, 0, 1" />
```

Then, as above, trigger a storyboard to begin on the Loaded event of the Viewport3D.  In either case, if you need more control over the animation, you can make your storyboard a named resource to be referenced by other events, or even build and control it entirely in code.

- [More about 2D transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx)
- [More about 3D transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753347.aspx)