# create 3d application menu in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i want create an application with 3d menu and 3d animation like that you all saw in apple mobile or mac os etc.

for example i want to create a menu like this site demo [Sample](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/technology-video/9118028/Soluto-Metro-Style-app-demo.html)

when i saw the site demo i decide create a menu with buttons (like metro style buttons) and when buttons clicked, the button rotate(i mean 3d rotation around y axis) and it grow up(scale animation) then in back of that button user see the page he want.(exact like demo in site)

for this issue i search alot and find helpfull sites like this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168420/wpf-rotating-button) and i can create some thing like that i want for one button.(but not exact that i want)

now i want add 3 or 4 Viewport2DVisual3D (my own buttons) in viewport 3d then locate them where i want then do those animation for them.

1.if it is possible how can i do that?

2.if i choose wrong way please some one show true way for this issue.

3.if some one know more perfect menu show it to me please

see that i create here [MyCode](http://mamadreflex.persiangig.com/Project/Debug.rar)

"im using wpf application with VS2010"