# Rotate a panel 90º

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a panel in winform and I need rotate it 90 degrees when I click on the button.

I have looking for this in google and in other questions, but they have no answer....

here is my panel [image]

And how I need

[image]

Comment: What is the content of the panel that is so important to rotate?

Comment: what are you rotating? Do you want to rotate drawings on the panel or you want to rotate its controls?

Comment: I have multiple checkBoxes and I need to rotate this when user click in this option

Comment: @illDev: do checkboxes have to be rotated too? do you limited with winforms only, or you can built-in WPF control in your winforms application?

Comment: You must work with locations of the controls, you can't use some sort of matrix to rotate. You'll need to recalculate new locations and set them like ckeckBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic The position is not the problem. The problem is rotate...

Comment: You can owner draw the controls so that they are rotated but FYI it won't be easy.

Comment: Do the CheckBoxes have any text? I see no text in the attached image. If yes, do you need to rotate the texts?

Comment: Yes, what I need is rotate the Checkboxes...I mean that rotate the panel with they  is easist than rotate all checkboxes...Yes, they have texts

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to rotate a panel in WinForms.

To rotate objects on a form, I've always had to use WPF.

Here is an intro to WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18232/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-1-XAML

The specific part about rotation is in part 3 on data binding.

Comment: I have downloaded a sample code ..but I not quite understood..Can you help me?

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with? Keep in mind that this is not traditional winform application development, and you must utilize the XAML to really take advantage of the additional features in WPF.

Comment: In source which I have downloaded, has a game...In this game the panel rotate...but in this sample have multiple concepts from WPF and it's confused for beginners ...I need only rotate a panel ;S

Comment: @illDev Well, you need to *learn* WPF first.

Comment: @illDev It will be difficult for you to understand all of the differences between WPF and winforms if you don't take the time to learn them. The rotation feature is part of XAML.